# Automatically search all fields for all models in django admin

Tags: django, django-models

I want to be able to search all models for all fields in Django admin, without having to setup ModelAdmin and searchfields individually.

example:

I have all my models in model.py:

```py
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
from django.db import models

class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    starting_node = models.ForeignKey('Node', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'diagnosis'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Diag #' + str(self.id) + ' - ' + self.code


class DiagnosisHistory(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_user = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    report = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    json_report = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'diagnosis_history'

# and so on
```

and the admin.py where I register the models:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from . import models


# Do not care. Register everything
for cls in [cls for name, cls in models.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)]:
    admin.site.register(cls)
```

I don't want to run through each Model and manually create a ModelAdmin with each field

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models as django_models

from . import models


relationship_fields = (django_models.ManyToManyField, django_models.ForeignKey, django_models.OneToOneField)

for cls in [cls for name, cls in models.__dict__.items() if isinstance(cls, type)]:
    meta_fields = [field.name for field in cls._meta.local_fields if not isinstance(field, relationship_fields)]

    class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        search_fields = meta_fields
    admin.site.register(cls, Admin)
```

Note: registering all fields will fail since some are relationships. using `cls._meta.local_fields` exclude inferred relationships but you also need to exclude fields such as foreign keys defined in your model. Thus, we filter with `isinstance(field, relationship_fields)`

Note 2: I should probably use get_fields since local_fields seems to be private API (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/meta/)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    search_fields = [field.name for field in MyModel._meta.fields]
    # ...
```

Comment: This is all fields for one model. The question is for searching across all models.